# Drawing an obtuse triangle, and marking its height

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to have an obtuse triangle with vertices A, B, and C drawn. The lengths of the sides are to be labeled a, b, and c. If the angle at C is the obtuse angle, the height of the triangle is to be drawn as a dashed line segment from A, and the side BC is to be extended as a dashed line segment to the point P of its intersection with the dashed line segment indicating the height of the triangle.

I would also like the angle marked with one "|" to be an interior angle, and I would like the lengths of the sides to be outside the triangle. What does `[auto]` in `\tkzLabelSegment[auto]` tell TikZ to draw?

I guess that a command like `\tkzDefPointWith[orthogonal normed,K=blah](B,C)` is to be used.  Is there a manual describing some of the commands of `tkz-euclide`?  I just saw that there is a command `\tkzDefTriangle[equilateral]` for having TikZ calculate the coordinates of the third vertex of a triangle given its two other vertices so as to get an equilateral triangle.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\tkzDefPoint(0,-1){C}
\tkzDefPoint(4,1){B}
\tkzDefPoint(-1,3){A}


\tkzLabelPoint[left](A){$A$}
\tkzLabelPoint[right](B){$B$}
\tkzLabelPoint[below](C){$C$}


\tkzDrawSegment[green!60!black](A,C)
\tkzDrawSegment[green!60!black](C,B)
\tkzDrawSegment[green!60!black](B,A)

\tkzLabelSegment[auto](B,A){$c$}
\tkzLabelSegment[auto,swap](B,C){$a$}
\tkzLabelSegment[auto,swap](C,A){$b$}


\tkzMarkAngle[size=1cm,color=cyan,mark=|](C,B,A)
\tkzMarkAngle[size=1cm,color=cyan,mark=||](C,A,B)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Providing MWE with an image of its output is recommended to ease us understanding your case at a glance.

Comment: What prompted you to choose "cyanide-based food" as your user name?  How do I include the diagram that TikZ draws from my code on this site?  I like the code that Mark Wibrow provided. It gives me the diagram that I wanted.  I still have questions regarding my code.  Why is an exterior angle drawn at C?  Why are the lengths of the sides written inside the triangle?

Comment: Regarding the username, it is randomly chosen just for fun as usual. Regarding uploading your diagram, see my answer [here (click)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3156/19356). I am preparing my own answer for you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (120:3) coordinate (A) (0:3) coordinate (B) (0:0) coordinate (C);
\draw (A) 
  -- (B) node [at start, above left] {$A$} node [midway, above] {$c$}
  -- (C) node [at start, right]      {$B$} node [midway, below] {$a$}
  -- (A) node [at start, below]      {$C$} node [midway, below] {$b$}
  -- cycle;
\draw [dashed] (A) |- (C) node [midway, below left] {$P$};
\draw (0:.5) arc (0:120:.5) (60:.4) -- (60:.6);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or this...

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (80:3) coordinate (A) (-30:3) coordinate (B) (0:0) coordinate (C);
\draw (A) 
  -- (B) node [at start, above left] {$A$} node [midway, right] {$c$}
  -- (C) node [at start, right]      {$B$} node [midway, below] {$a$}
  -- (A) node [at start, below]      {$C$} node [midway, left]  {$b$}
  -- cycle;
\coordinate (P) at ($(B)!(A)!(C)$);
\draw [dashed] (A) -- (P) node [below left] {$P$} -- (C);
\draw ($(C)!0.5cm!(B)$) arc (-30:80:.5cm) node [midway, sloped] {$|$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a diagram of an obtuse triangle indicating its height.  This is the diagram that I said that I wanted.  I should have specified that I do not want any sides of the triangle to be horizontal or vertical.  To draw the dashed line segments indicating the height of such a triangle, you cannot use "\draw [dashed] (A) |- (C)node [midway, below left] {$P$};".  Can you give me the code for instructing TikZ to draw such a triangle?

Comment: @user60254, The `calc` library can be used for this, see my updated answer. Note that the position of the labels has to be changed as this is not done automatically.

Comment: This is the diagram that I wanted!  (You have an error in your code. You have "node [below left] {$P$} -- (C)".  You are missing a comma between "below" and "left".)

Comment: This is the diagram that I wanted!  (You have an error in your code.  You are missing a comma between "below" and "left" in the command to typeset the letter "P".)

Comment: @user60254 actually `below left` is a valid option. If it produces an error for you, then you may need to update your `PGF` version.

Answer (score 5):

A PSTricks solution using the [`pst-eucl`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-eucl) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\def\Label[#1]#2#3#4{
  \pcline[linestyle = none, offset = #1](#2)(#3)
  \ncput*{$#4$}
}

\begin{document}

\psset{unit = 0.9}
\begin{pspicture}(-0.35,-0.5)(12.5,8.4)
  \pnode(0,0){P}
  \pstTriangle(0,8){A}(12,0){B}(4,0){C}
 \psset{CodeFig, CodeFigColor = blue, LabelSep = 0.7}
  \pstMarkAngle{C}{A}{B}{$\alpha$}
  \pstMarkAngle{A}{B}{C}{$\beta$}
  \pstMarkAngle{B}{C}{A}{$\gamma$}
  \Label[8pt]{A}{B}{c}
  \Label[8pt]{B}{C}{a}
  \Label[-8pt]{A}{C}{b}
  \pstProjection{P}{C}{A}[P]
  \pstProjection[PointName = none]{A}{P}{C}[Q]
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output1]

or

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\def\Label[#1]#2#3#4{
  \pcline[linestyle = none, offset = #1](#2)(#3)
  \ncput*{$#4$}
}

\begin{document}

\psset{unit = 0.9}
\begin{pspicture}(-0.35,-0.5)(12.5,8.4)
  \pnode(0,0){P}
  \pstTriangle(0,8){A}(12,0){B}(4,0){C}
 \psset{CodeFig, CodeFigColor = blue, LabelSep = 0.8, MarkAngle = 90}
  \pstMarkAngle[Mark = MarkHash]{C}{A}{B}{$\alpha$}
  \pstMarkAngle[Mark = MarkHashh]{A}{B}{C}{$\beta$}
  \pstMarkAngle[Mark = MarkHashhh]{B}{C}{A}{$\gamma$}
  \Label[8pt]{A}{B}{c}
  \Label[8pt]{B}{C}{a}
  \Label[-8pt]{A}{C}{b}
  \pstProjection{P}{C}{A}[P]
  \pstProjection[PointName = none]{A}{P}{C}[Q]
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output2]

Answer (score 4):

Just for typing exercise with PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=20pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[CodeFigColor=.,shortput=nab](8,6)
    %
    % drawing the triangle
    \pstTriangle(0,6){A}(8,0){B}(3,0){C}
    %
    % projecting the point A onto BC (extension)
    \psline[linestyle=dashed](A|0,0)(C)
    \pstProjection[CodeFig]{B}{C}{A}[P]
    %
    % labeling and marking angles
    \psset{MarkAngleRadius=.5,LabelSep=1,MarkAngle=90}
    \pstMarkAngle[Mark=MarkHash]{C}{A}{B}{$\alpha$}
    \pstMarkAngle[Mark=MarkHashh]{A}{B}{C}{$\beta$}
    \pstMarkAngle[Mark=MarkHashhh]{B}{C}{A}{$\gamma$}
    %
    % labeling sides
    \psset{linestyle=none}
    \pcline(A)(B)^{$c$}
    \pcline(A)(C)_{$b$}
    \pcline(C)(B)_{$a$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Animated version

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=20pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\def\Atom#1{%
\begin{pspicture}[CodeFigColor=.,shortput=nab,saveNodeCoors,NodeCoorPrefix=N](8,6)
    %
    % drawing the triangle
    \pstTriangle(8,0){B}(3,0){C}(6;#1){A}
    %
    % projecting the point A onto BC (extension)
    \psline[linestyle=dashed](A|0,0)(C)
    \pstProjection[CodeFig]{B}{C}{A}[P]
    %
    % labeling and marking angles
    \psset{MarkAngleRadius=.5,LabelSep=1,MarkAngle=90}
    \pstMarkAngle[Mark=MarkHash]{C}{A}{B}{$\alpha$}
    \pstMarkAngle[Mark=MarkHashh]{A}{B}{C}{$\beta$}
    \pstMarkAngle[Mark=MarkHashhh]{B}{C}{A}{$\gamma$}
    %
    % labeling sides
    \psset{linestyle=none}
    \pcline(A)(B)^{$c$}
    \pcline(A)(C)_{$b$}
    \pcline(C)(B)_{$a$}
\end{pspicture}}

\begin{document}
\multido{\i=30+5}{13}{\Atom{\i}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

> What does [auto] in \tkzLabelSegment[auto] tell TikZ to draw?

`auto` is a `tikz` option to put the labels to the segments/curves such that they are not on the curve but next to it. If you add `swap` option additionally, `tikz` will mirror the label with respect to the line. See this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  Without any option to label node:

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- node {1} (2,3);
  \end{tikzpicture}

  With the option \verb|auto|:

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- node[auto] {1} (2,3);
  \end{tikzpicture}

  With the option \verb|auto| and \verb|swap|:

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- node[auto,swap] {1} (2,3);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To draw the perpendicular you can use

```
\tkzDrawAltitude[dashed,color=magenta](C,B)(A)
```

which tells `tikz` to draw a perpendicular from `A` onto the segment `CB`.

Now the code with comments in it for explanation:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\tkzDefPoint(0:0){C}
\tkzDefPoint(0:3){B}
\tkzDefPoint(120:3){A}



\tkzLabelPoint[left](A){$A$}
\tkzLabelPoint[right](B){$B$}
\tkzLabelPoint[below](C){$C$}

\tkzDrawSegment[green!60!black](A,C)
\tkzDrawSegment[green!60!black](C,B)
\tkzDrawSegment[green!60!black](A,B)

\tkzDrawAltitude[dashed,color=magenta](C,B)(A)   %% draw the perpendicular
\tkzGetPoint{P}                                  %% get the point P
\tkzLabelPoint[below](P){$P$}                    %% label the point P
\tkzDrawSegment[dashed,color=magenta](C,P)       %% draw CP

\tkzLabelSegment[auto,swap](B,A){$c$}
\tkzLabelSegment[auto](B,C){$a$}
\tkzLabelSegment[auto](C,A){$b$}


%% here use the correct order. For example, BCA is inner angle and ACB is outer angle
\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.5cm,color=cyan,mark=|](B,C,A)
\tkzMarkAngle[size=1cm,color=cyan,mark=||](C,A,B)
\tkzMarkAngle[size=1cm,color=cyan,mark=|||](A,B,C)

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

> Is there a manual describing some of the commands of tkz-euclide?

`tkz-euclide-screen` is the manual for `tkz-euclide` and unfortunately it is in French (Allain is French). But it has sample codes to illustrate almost all the commands. You can get it by `texdoc tkz-euclide` from your command line/terminal or from [texdoc.net](http://texdoc.net). You have to read `tikz` manual too along with `tkz-euclide-screen`.

Comment: Thanks for answering my questions regarding syntax and commands. Maybe I will use a French-to-English translation web site to read the manual that you suggested.